# Which partition is the Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, wubi, encryption, truecrypt

I am encrypting my entire Ubuntu partition with TrueCrypt, but I am not sure which one is the Ubuntu partition?

I have dual boot Ubuntu with the other being Windows Vista which has basically no information on it anymore.

[Here's a picture of the partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Bmj.jpg):
[image: list of partitions]

Answer (score 1):

You can't encrypt your entire Ubuntu partition with Truecrypt, it would not boot anymore. If you wish to achieve a fully encrypted Ubuntu install, then try out the [alternate image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/), which has an option to fully encrypt your Ubuntu partition (except for /boot).

Also, I can tell from the mount points in your screenshot that you used [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/) to install Ubuntu. This is not a "proper" Ubuntu setup, since it basically resides in a file on your Windows partition. Consider re-installing Ubuntu the regular way, that is, by booting your computer from a Ubuntu live-cd/-usb.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question: sda2 would be ubuntu because it was installed second, is using a mount directory and im assuming you gave it more than 1.5 gb.

but [Cumulus007](https://askubuntu.com/users/77111/cumulus007)'s advice should be followed anyways